# Logstash resurrect connection to dead ES instance 401

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am new to elastic stack. Our existing deployment is on VMs… services, filbeat, log stash, elastic, kibana.
We are evaluating elastic cloud where I created a trial account. My nomad deployments will generate logs which I want to push to es cloud deployment. I added cloud id, api key to my configuration. But I get below error:

```
[logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"https://abc1234.canadacentral.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError,
 :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'https://abc1234.canadacentral.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/'"}
```

This seems authorisation error. Would I need to use ca cert in my log stash config?
Also, I see two cloud IDs… one on manage this deployment screen which I have used in my log stash config. The other cloud id is visible on left menu->enterprise search-> elastic search screen. The two IDs are different. Which one should I use?
Would appreciate pointers. Thanks.